# I'm getting warning "floating point overflow "

Tags: c, floating-point, type-conversion

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
  short int b = (short int)(((-100) * (1UL << 6)) - 0.5);
  short int c = (short int)( (-6400) - 0.5 );

  printf("%d",sizeof(short int));
  printf("\n%d",b);
  printf("\n%d",c);
}
```

output :

> b : 32767
>
> c : -6400

Why I'm getting different results?
Is this because of type conversion?

Since I cant put the exact copy of code here, I wrote the part that showing up the warning in the Codepad and pasted it here.
I'm using Posek compiler.
The above expression is used in one of the configuration. When I run the code in Trace32, I came to know that it has acquired the value "-1". I'm not getting how the value "-1" came ?

Compiler is displaying :

> warning : floating point overflow

Comment: i mean Arithmetic conversion between signed and unsigned numbers.

Comment: Your title mentions a "floating point overflow" warning. Is that a compile-time warning?

Comment: I am curious what compiler you are using, I am not seeing a similar warning using `gcc` or `clang`.

Comment: @KeithThompson yes its a compile-time warning.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour i'm using a posek compiler. and its giving value "-1"

Comment: Then please include the exact copy-and-pasted warning in your question.

Comment: this line: short int c = (short int)( (-6400) - 0.5 ); (and the one before it) have a few problems.  short is only 64k-1 max value  then a double value ( 0.5 ) is part of the equation. the result is -6400 is converted to double then further decremented to -6400.5 then converted to a short int (via conversion to ;short int (truncates the fractional part. so the result is -6400

Comment: the use of UL1 <<6 in this line: short int b = (short int)(((-100) * (1UL << 6)) - 0.5); is resulting in the use of unsigned long int math, which is the reason for the difference int the result.  BTW: both those lines are really bad code and both lines are calculated at compile time, not execution time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
(-100) * (1UL << 6)
          ^^^
```

Multiplication performs the usual arithmetic conversions on its operands and then the integer promotions for this case and that caused `-100` to be converted to unsigned long which means it will have a very large unsigned value which does not fit into signed short. This is singed integer overflow which is undefined behavior.

The fix would be as follows:

```
(-100) * (1 << 6)
          ^^
```

Note that `sizeof` does not return an *int* the correct format specifier for `printf` would be `%zu`.

Turning up the warnings on your compiler really helps, using `clang` and the following flags `-std=c99  -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic` I received the following warnings:

```
warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'int' to 'unsigned long' [-Wsign-conversion]
short int b = (short int)(((-100) * (1UL << 6)) - 0.5);
                            ^~~~  ~

warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'unsigned long' [-Wformat]
printf("%d",sizeof(short int));
        ~~  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       %lu
```

For reference the draft C99 standard section `6.5.5` *Multiplicative operators* says:

> The usual arithmetic conversions are performed on the operands.

and section `6.3.1.8` *Usual arithmetic conversions* says:

> Otherwise, the integer promotions are performed on both operands. Then
>   the following rules are applied to the promoted operands:

and for this, the following applies since `-100` will be *int*  and the other operand is *unsigned long*:

> Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank
>   greater or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then
>   the operand with signed integer type is converted to the type of the
>   operand with unsigned integer type.

Comment: i agree with you. i knew its because of Arithmetic conversions. i've used the above expression in one of my configuration. I'm using posek compiler. When i run the code in Trace32, the configuration has the value -1. So i'm not getting how "-1" has come up ?

Comment: @Harsha I am not familiar with posek. When you say *the above expression* do you mean `(short int)(((-100) * (1UL << 6)) - 0.5)`? Perhaps Trace32 handles the overflow differently.

Comment: Yes the same expression.